# How to read an embedded field in Go?

Tags: go

I design a new Request structure, but in some scenarios(http.Redirect), I need to get the origin `http.Request`.

My Request struct:

```
type Request struct {
    *http.Request
}

func (r *Request) IsGet() bool {
    return strings.EqualFold("GET", r.Method)
}
```

Main function:

```
    req := http.Request{
        Method:"POST",
    }

    myReq := &Request{&req}

    // How to get original request.
    originalReq, ok := (interface{}(*myReq)).(http.Request);
    if ok {
        fmt.Printf("Method: %s\n", originalReq.Method)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Failure")
    }
```

Comment: `myReq.Request`.  Take the Tour of Go, read Effective Go and the language spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what [the language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) says:

> The unqualified type name acts as the field name.
>
> ```
> // A struct with four anonymous fields of type T1, *T2, P.T3 and *P.T4
> struct {
>   T1        // field name is T1
>   *T2       // field name is T2
>   P.T3      // field name is T3
>   *P.T4     // field name is T4
>   x, y int  // field names are x and y
> }
> ```

i.e. `myReq.Request`